# Optimize the for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, iteration

Good, I currently have the following code:

```
n = 0
with open('/home/user/test.filter') as f:

    lines = f.readlines()

    for l in lines:
        if lines[n].startswith('-A vlan_8'):
            if "-o bond1.8" in lines[n]:
                    f = open('vlan8.filter_in', 'a')
                    f.write(l)
            else:
                f = open('vlan8.filter_out', 'a')
                f.write(l)
        if lines[n].startswith('-A vlan_10'):
            if "-o bond1.10" in lines[n]:
                f = open('vlan10.filter_in', 'a')
                f.write(l)
            else:
                f = open('vlan10.filter_out', 'a')
                f.write(l)
        if lines[n].startswith('-A vlan_15'):
            if "-o bond1.15" in lines[n]:
                f = open('vlan15.filter_in', 'a')
                f.write(l)
            else:
                f = open('vlan15.filter_out', 'a')
                f.write(l)

        # [...]

        n = n + 1
```

I thought about optimizing it with some accumulator or list to not make the script so extensive. Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume your tabs are a bit incorrect in this example?

Comment: You mean optimizing (faster) or refactoring (less repetition) ?

Comment: First, don't do `== True` - it is redundant; if the expression on the left side of `==` is equal to `True`, then, well, it's true. Second, as you have very similar code repeated multiple times, consider making it a function. Third, open your output files once, at the beginning, rather than opening them every time you need to write to them - you can keep a list, or better, a dict   of them.

Comment: You could only open the files (e.g. _vlan8.filter\_in_) __once__ before the loop, not for every line that you process. Also, all the `if` clauses immediately under the `for` loop (except the first of course) could be turned into `elif`s. `if lines[n].startswith` is incorrect, it should be `if lines.startswith`, but I __didn't edit them__ to avoid changing the semantics of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. Maintain a list of these numbers as so:

```
numList = [8, 10, 15, ...]
```

Now, all you need is a little string formatting.

```
with open('/home/user/test.filter') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for i, l in enumerate(lines): # I've used enumerate to eliminate n but really you don't need it
    for num in numList:
        if l.startswith('-A vlan_%d' %num):
            if "-o bond1.%d" %num in l:
                f = open('vlan%d.filter_in' %num, 'a')
            else:
                f = open('vlan%d.filter_out' %num, 'a')

            f.write(l)
            f.close()
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make the code cleaner, not faster. If that is so maybe this would work:

```
import re

parameter_re = re.compile(r'^-A vla_(\d+).*')

with open('data.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    # Match required parameter
    match = parameter_re.match(line)

    # Skip line if it doesn't match the required parameter
    if not match:
        continue

    # Extract number from parameter
    number = int(match.group(1))

    # Create output parameter string
    output_str = '-o bond1.%d' % number

    # Select correct filename to save the line
    if output_str in line:
        output_filename = 'vlan%d.filter_in' % number
    else:
        output_filename = 'vlan%d.filter_out' % number

    # Write the line to the correct file
    with open(output_filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write(line)
```

And if you want to make it shorter (which I don't recommend, better for it to be readable):

```
import re

with open('data.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    match = re.match(r'^-A vla_(\d+).*', line)
    if not match:
        continue
    number = int(match.group(1))
    if '-o bond1.%d' % number in line:
        output_filename = 'vlan%d.filter_in' % number
    else:
        output_filename = 'vlan%d.filter_out' % number
    with open(output_filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write(line)
```